# Is it possible to create a static filter rule based on a text pattern in GNUCash?

Tags: gnucash, ofx

Is it possible to create a static filter rule based on a text pattern in GNUCash during importing an OFX file? For example, its Import Matcher filter does not classify a transaction to a expense account automatically, but the text is the same every time:

```
REND PAGO APLIC AUT MAIS
```

If possible, the best place to apply this rule would be in the OFX import. I already trained the Import Matcher several times, to no avail.

Comment: Huh, What are you trying to do? Follow https://www.gnucash.org/docs/v4/C/gnucash-guide/importing-from-files.html and use the import matcher.

Comment: I'm trying to set a fixed rule in the import matcher for an OFX file, instead of only using the bayesian filter that, for some reason, does not classify correctly some transactions, doesn't matter the number of training samples that I provided and classified in the past.

Comment: I download a csv file, add accounts in a spreadsheet, then import that file with the Bayesian filter turned off.